# Firefox offsets button within parent div

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have the following simplified HTML/CSS which presents differently in Firefox v36 (when compared to IE v11 or Chrome v41).

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.pushbutton {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.pushbutton button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
}
.pushbutton button span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 8pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="pushbutton">
  <button type="button">
    <span>TopLeft</span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="pushbutton">
  <button type="button">
    <span>TopLeft</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

In Firefox v36 the result is the following:

[image: Firefox output]

I have experimented with it and found that adding either of the following will resolve the issue:

```
.pushbutton button {
    display: block;
}
```

or:

```
.pushbutton button {
    position: absolute;
}
```

I would however like to understand why this is happening and what is the best way to handle this thats compatible across browsers (including old ones!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`button {vertical-align: top;}` should solve your problem. The buttons are `inline-block` elements and the initial value of the `vertical-align` property is `baseline` which causes the gap in your red box.

Comment: I like your answer. Can you explain though why Chrome and IE don't show the same behaviour?

Comment: @karmasponge Because almost every browser has it's own base or initial line-height. And the "baseline" position is controlled by the given line-height.